# Stream URL not playing on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, stream, mp3, http-live-streaming

How to play this stream URL on wordpress?
http://live.mp3quran.net:9960/;

I tried to add .mp3 at the end of the URL:
http://live.mp3quran.net:9960/;.mp3

Both are working on any browser, but not inside the WordPress!

I tried many audio plugins player, also tried to wrap the file [embed] < audio > .. etc
nothing worked!

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

That is related to the https:// on your page and the stream being http://

Try a relay server or upgrade your stream provider